# run function when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I want to call the function when page loads to show the values in m2 and totalpris but my document.onlods() kills the functions. Don't know what I have done wrong (cauase I dont understand javascripts actuallay :) )
But the function works without my onload rows

```
<input id="bredd" type="text" value="2" /> 
<input id="djup" type="text" value="3" />
<input id="m2" type="text" value="" />
<input id="m2pris" type="text" value="500" />
<input id="totalpris" type="text" value="" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.onload=ready(document.getElementById('m2'));
    document.onload=ready(document.getElementById('totalpris'));

    $('#bredd').keyup(calculate);
    $('#djup').keyup(calculate);
    $('#m2pris').keyup(calculate);
});

function calculate(e)
{
    $('#m2').val($('#bredd').val() * $('#djup').val());
    $('#totalpris').val($('#m2').val() * $('#m2pris').val());
}
</script>
```

Comment: What does `ready()` do? The function you call inside the DOM ready

Comment: $(document).ready() when DOM is loaded or $(window).load() when all elements are loaded (including script / img)

Comment: `window.onload = function() { calculate() }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ready()
```

**Description:** Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

```
$(document).ready() {
    calculate();
    //and anything else
}
```